# .NET Core reload on save issue while working on referenced class libraries

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, .net-core

I'm using

```
dotnet watch run
```

To have my .net core (3.1) web api reload on save automatically and it's working pretty great so far. However i have created a new solution with some class library projects, along with the web api one, and when applying changes to a referenced class library the changes do not reflect through the api calls, unless i specifically hit save while on the api project.

Is there anyway i can make watch reload project when i save changes to a referenced class library?
Thanks.

Comment: Based on this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/dotnet-watch?view=aspnetcore-3.1#custom-watch-projects) and this [link](https://github.com/dotnet/AspNetCore/tree/master/src/Tools/dotnet-watch) (Project References section) it should do that by default. Do you use any parameters for `dotnet watch run`? What is your folder structure?

Comment: @Akos Interesting, here is my project structure https://i.imgur.com/JozGarW.png
Changes made to (for instance) FixtureManager.cs will not be updated after hitting save on the Web API project, even though the 'module' is referenced there